# Jenkins upstream parent projects block executors and downstream projects sit pending causing deadlock

Tags: concurrency, jenkins, blocking

I have a situation where there are multiple parent jobs:

```
A    B      C       D      E     F
```

and one shared downstream job:

```
X
```

which runs as a triggered build from each of the parent projects.

The parents block until X returns and then do some other tasks.

Ideally I would like only one of these job pipelines to run at any one time. So if A were fired up, and B right after. A then X needs to run, then B then X needs to run.

Now when I setup jenkins with only 1 executor. Only the parent fires up and it blocks forever.

If I add another executor. I end up in a situation where two parents might take up the executor slots.

so say A, B and C are fired up. A runs, fires X, X completes, B and C occupy the two slots and now X can't be launched by either....

What would be the simplest way to get around this?

Comment: Is this a Maven project? I don't quite get the project setup — you can only have a single parent in Maven. Could you post a minimal dependency configuration?

Comment: When you say: "The parents block" - what exactly do you mean, or rather how do you configure this? Are the parent jobs just restricted to where they can run? We have a similar configuration and last week the jobs were blocking each other.